# Add class if element is checked, but on load not click

Tags: jquery, find, parent, checked

So I have this html code:

```
<div class="panel-radioimage">
<div class="radio-image-wrapper">
<label for="1"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bluestudio5/images/patterns/1.png" alt="image" class="admin-patterns">
<div class="check-list"></div></label>
<input class="farm_img_pattern" type="radio" name="farm_img_pattern" value="1.png" checked>
</div>
```

I have few of these elements on page, and I want to add class "checked-list" to class "check-list" when input is checked on page load. SO I tried this that worked before with click event:

```
 if(jQuery('.farm_img_pattern').is(':checked')){
        jQuery(this).parent().find(".check-list").addClass("checked-list");
    }
```

but its not working. Problem is with "this" Anyone know solution for getting checked element on page load ?

Comment: Why can't you just use jQuery(".check-list").addClass("checked-list") instead of jQuery(this).parent().find(...) ?

Comment: And why are using a radio button if there is only one item that has to be  checked.. A checkbox makes more sense here .. And if it's a single radio button you are talking about it will always be checked when you click on it

Comment: There is much more items, but I added just one line of it to keep it clean. I have 10 of these elements on page, same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
jQuery('.farm_img_pattern').filter(':checked').each(function(index) {
    jQuery(this).parent().find(".check-list").addClass("checked-list");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `click` event, `this` will be the element clicked. Just use the selector for the element:

```
if(jQuery('.farm_img_pattern').is(':checked')){
  jQuery('.farm_img_pattern').parent().find(".check-list").addClass("checked-list");
}
```

Comment: this way, its adding class to all check-list elements on page, i have plenty of them.

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic: Oh, I missed that. I assumed that you only had a single one, as you only have a single `if` statement to check it.